# Fetch Facebook Calendar URL using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, calendar

I'm trying to fetch the URL of the Calendar of a user (not a page), specifically containing birthdays, using the Graph API. I'm able to do it manually on the Facebook site (using instructions from [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/152652248136178/)) but I want to automate it using the Graph API. In the documentation I'm only able to find details about [extracting events related to a page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/), but not for a user. Does anybody have any experience with extracting the URL of a Facebook Calendar containing the birthdays of the friends of a user?

P.S: It is of the form `webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/b.php?uid=xxxxxx&key=yyyyyy`

Comment: There is no API for that. Accessing a user’s birthday requires that they grant your app permission first. And scraping is not allowed.